# Do there exist any elastomers that do not contain carbon?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, rubber

Elastomers (rubbery materials) that I know of either have a carbon backbone or a silicone backbone with carbon-containing side chains. Do there exist any elastomers that do not contain carbon atoms?

So far Google couldn't come up with anything, but I hope to get a more definitive answer here.

Comment: Yes, there are, e.g. [poly(dichlorophosphazene)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(dichlorophosphazene))

Comment: Beat me by seconds... Polyphosphazenes in general are a good place to look. Why the downvote??

Comment: Are you thinking of "elastomer" in some specific sense other than just being "springy"? Or just being springy at normal conditions? Thin films of glass or many metals are pretty springy.